# Spark function aliases - performant udfs

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

#### Context

In many of the sql queries I write, I find myself combining spark predefined functions in the exact same way, which often results in **verbose and duplicated code**, and my developer instinct is to want to refactor it.

So, my question is this : is there some way to define some kind of **alias** for function combinations without resorting to udfs (which are to avoid for perofmance reasons) - the goal being to make the code clearer and cleaner. Essentially, what I want is something like `udfs` but without the performance penalty. Also, these function **MUST be callable from within a spark-sql query usable in `spark.sql` calls.**

#### Example

For example, let's say my business logic is to reverse some string and hash it like this : (please note that the function combination here is irrelevant, what is important is that it is some combination of existing pre-defined spark functions - possibly many of them)

```
SELECT 
    sha1(reverse(person.name)),
    sha1(reverse(person.some_information)),
    sha1(reverse(person.some_other_information))
    ...
FROM person
```

Is there a way of declaring a `business` function without paying the performance price of using a `udf`, allowing the code just above to be rewritten as :

```
SELECT 
    business(person.name),
    business(person.some_information),
    business(person.some_other_information)
    ...
FROM person
```

I have searched around quite a bit on the spark documentation and on this website and have not found a way of achieving this, which is pretty weird to me because it looks like a pretty natural need, and I don't understand why you should necessarly pay the **black-box** price of defining and calling a udf.

Comment: I think you may have answered your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way of declaring a business function without paying the performance price of using a udf

You don't have to use `udf`, you might extend `Expression` class, or for the simplest operations - `UnaryExpression`. Then you will have to implement just several methods and here we go. It is natively integrated into Spark, besides that letting use some advantage features such as code generation.

In your case adding `business` function is pretty straightforward:

```
def business(column: Column): Column = {
  sha1(reverse(column))
}
```

> MUST be callable from within a spark-sql query usable in spark.sql calls

This is more tricky but achievable.
You need to create custom functions registrar:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.FunctionIdentifier
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression 

object FunctionAliasRegistrar {

val funcs: mutable.Map[String, Seq[Column] => Column] = mutable.Map.empty

  def add(name: String, builder: Seq[Column] => Column): this.type = {
    funcs += name -> builder
    this
  }

  def registerAll(spark: SparkSession) = {
    funcs.foreach { case (alias, builder) => {
      def b(children: Seq[Expression]) = builder.apply(children.map(expr => new Column(expr))).expr
      spark.sessionState.functionRegistry.registerFunction(FunctionIdentifier(alias), b)
    }}
  }
}
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
FunctionAliasRegistrar
  .add("business1", child => lower(reverse(child.head)))
  .add("business2", child => upper(reverse(child.head)))
  .registerAll(spark) 

dataset.createTempView("data")

spark.sql(
  """
    | SELECT business1(name), business2(name) FROM data
    |""".stripMargin)
.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|lower(reverse(name))|upper(reverse(name))|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|sined               |SINED               |
|taram               |TARAM               |
|1taram              |1TARAM              |
|2taram              |2TARAM              |
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is indeed exactly what I needed. I just tested it (spark 2.4.2) and it seems like if you're willing to use the constructor of the Column class instead of using `Column.apply`in the `registerAll` method, then you don't need to put the `FunctionRegistrar`object in `org.apache.spark.sql` ! (Maybe it would be nice to update the answer with this change since it makes the whole thing look less like a hack and more like a clean extension !
Many thanks :)

Comment: Haven't noticed that, will update the answer, thank you.

Comment: Second part nice.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to do this with pyspark, I have a python function that returns a column expression and I'd like to be able to use in the sql syntax as well as the pyspark without having to create two functions. Thanks